# Pandas UDF with dictionary lookup and conditionals

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas, pandas-udf

I want to use pandas_udf in Pyspark for certain transformations and calculations of column. And it seems that pandas udf can't be written exactly as normal UDFs.

An example function looks something like below:

```
def modify_some_column(example_column_1, example_column_2):

    lookup_dict = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3,'d': 4, 'e' : 5} #can be anything

    if example_column_1 in lookup_dict:
        if(example_column_1 == 'a' and example_column_2 == "something"):
            return lookup_dict[example_column_1]
        
        elif(example_column_1 == 'a' and example_column_2 == "something else"):
        
            return "something else"
        else:
            return lookup_dict[example_column_1]    
    else:
        return ""
```

Basically, takes in two column values from a spark dataframe and returns a value which I intend to use with `withColumn`:

```
modify_some_column_udf  = pandas_udf(modify_some_column, returnType= StringType())
df = df.withColumn('new_col',modify_property_type_udf(df.col_1,df.col_2))
```

But this does not work. How should I modify the above to be able to use it in pandas udf?

Edit: It is clear to me that the above conditions can be easily and efficiently be implemented using native PySpark functions. But I am looking to write the above logic using Pandas UDF.

Comment: Provide sample input and expected outcome

Comment: Above is a generic example. I expect for each row, a new column named ,"new_col" in the dataframe value for which is returned by the modify_some_function using params as values of col_1 and col_2 of the same row of the dataframe.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this simple if/else logic, you don't have to use UDF. In fact you should avoid to use UDFs as much as possible.

Assuming you have the dataframe as follow

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('a', 'something'),
    ('a', 'something else'),
    ('c', None),
    ('c', ''),
    ('c', 'something'),
    ('c', 'something else'),
    ('c', 'blah'),
    ('f', 'blah'),
], ['c1', 'c2'])
df.show()

+---+--------------+
| c1|            c2|
+---+--------------+
|  a|     something|
|  a|something else|
|  c|          null|
|  c|              |
|  c|     something|
|  c|something else|
|  c|          blah|
|  f|          blah|
+---+--------------+
```

You can create a temporary lookup column and use it to check against other columns

```
import json
your_lookup_dict = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3,'d': 4, 'e' : 5}

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('lookup', F.from_json(F.lit(json.dumps(your_lookup_dict)), 'map<string, string>'))
    .withColumn('mod', F
        .when((F.col('c1') == 'a') & (F.col('c2') == 'something'), F.col('lookup')[F.col('c1')])
        .when((F.col('c1') == 'a') & (F.col('c2') == 'something else'), F.lit('something else'))
        .otherwise(F.col('lookup')[F.col('c1')])
    )
    .show(10, False)
)

+---+--------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+
|c1 |c2            |lookup                                  |mod           |
+---+--------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+
|a  |something     |{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5}|1             |
|a  |something else|{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5}|something else|
|c  |null          |{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5}|3             |
|c  |              |{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5}|3             |
|c  |something     |{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5}|3             |
|c  |something else|{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5}|3             |
|c  |blah          |{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5}|3             |
|f  |blah          |{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 5}|null          |
+---+--------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+
```

#### EDIT

Since you insisted to use Pandas UDF, you'd have to understand that Pandas execute your dataframe by batches, so you'll have to wrap your functions to something like this

```
def wrapper(iterator):
    def modify_some_column(example_column_1, example_column_2):
        lookup_dict = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3,'d': 4, 'e' : 5} #can be anything
        if example_column_1 in lookup_dict:
            if(example_column_1 == 'a' and example_column_2 == "something"):
                return str(lookup_dict[example_column_1])
            elif(example_column_1 == 'a' and example_column_2 == "something else"):
                return "something else"
            else:
                return str(lookup_dict[example_column_1])    
        else:
            return ""

    for pdf in iterator:
        pdf['mod'] = pdf.apply(lambda r: modify_some_column(r['c1'], r['c2']), axis=1)
        yield pdf

df = df.withColumn('mod', F.lit('temp'))
df.mapInPandas(wrapper, df.schema).show()

+---+--------------+--------------+
| c1|            c2|           mod|
+---+--------------+--------------+
|  a|     something|             1|
|  a|something else|something else|
|  c|          null|             3|
|  c|              |             3|
|  c|     something|             3|
|  c|something else|             3|
|  c|          blah|             3|
|  f|          blah|              |
+---+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I understand that udf are not advisable and it but there is a requirement to write it in pandas UDF. How would the above logic translate in that case if we are not worried about performance.

Comment: @Tarique please check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you. And this will still be less performant than a native Pyspark implementation?

Comment: Yes, of course :)